# How to remove the inherited style on Text Box object from <td> that the text box is nested in

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How can I remove the inherited properties?

[image: the html tags are displayed below]

Comment: @ To clear the question I want to make the input box wider to show complete sentence...! But the intherited properties do not let me to do that! I add the width attribute but it did not work.. if I remove the inheried styles, it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can't remove the inherited properties. You need to override them with "stronger" CSS rules. You can use the !important keyword if you need to.

```
    .TaskFormField {
      font-size: 10px !important;
    }

    .TaskFormField {
      font-size: 12px; /* One could believe that the font size should be 12px,
                  but it remains 10px because the !important keyword is used. */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question is? From the snippet of HTML it looks like you have a "TaskFormField" class on your table column and that is what is showing up in your style box. If you want to over-ride for the input you can do something like:

.TaskFormField input {color:#000; font-size:10pt; font-family:Arial,Verdana,Sans-Serif;}